# How to implement SSO from Mobile App to Web App

Tags: c#, session, cookies, auth0, hybrid-mobile-app

I am currently working on a mobile app project that lacks a specific functionality available on the web version. To address this, I am integrating the web version's functionality into my app. The mobile app utilizes native biometrics to store the refresh token securely on the device, whereas the web app uses simple cookie authentication. I am seeking a solution to implement Single Sign-On (SSO) from the mobile app to the web app, given the mentioned scenario.

Any assistance or suggestions you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

I have been reading articles and getting mixed responses from people. Some say it can not be done while others say it can.

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/8517948). You are encouraged to make an attempt. If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.